# How to swap an Ethereum ERC-20 and Neo NEP5 token with a smart contract?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, neo-crypto

I am trying to understand how to swap tokens between blockchains...

lets assume the following:

- I have a smart contract in ETH that issue a token (ABC) as ERC-20 token
- I have a smart contract in NEO that issue a token (ABC) as NEP5 token

How can I consolidate them in one blockchain? (all in ETH or all in NEO?)

How do ICO's handle multi-concurrency collection?

Thanks All

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Each blockchain is its own seperated administration. Therefor it is not possible to swap tokens on-chain as you would need the first chain to rely on stuff that happens on another chain.
To do something like this, usually, you need a third party that guarantees that the exchange happens correctly. 
An example of such a service is "ShapeShift". Take a look at what their service is about here:
https://shapeshift.io/

Just realise that the management of swapping is an off-chain process in this case.

Neo is unique in that it describes a mechanism in which off chain assets can be exchanged atomically, which is referred to in their whitepaper as "NeoX". Ontology is a collection of protocols of wich part is a implementation of the NeoX concept.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.... but how does an atomic swap work? isn't what I am looking for?

Comment: Seems like your question might be a bit elaborate for StackOverflow. I recommend reading the whitepaper of both Neo and Ontology to get a grasp of the under the hood technology. Also you'd need to find a way to do the atomicity on the end of Ethereum.